# Asp.Net(C#) inline coding one more eval Merge

Tags: c#, asp.net

How to make one more eval merge ?

```
<asp:HiddenField ID="HiddenField1" runat="server" Value='<%# Eval("Name"),Eval("Surname"),Eval("Mail")%>'/>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try

```
<asp:HiddenField ID="HiddenField1" runat="server" Value='<%# Eval("Name") + "," + Eval("Surname") + "," + Eval("Mail")%>'/>
```